# OnCheckedChanged event handler of asp:checkbox does not fire when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

I have a repeater, in each ItemTemplate of the repeater is an asp:checkbox with an OnCheckedChanged event handler set. The checkboxes have the AutoPostBack property set to true. When any of the checkboxes is checked, the event handler fires. When any is unchecked, the event handler does not fire.

Any idea why the event does not fire, and how I mgiht make it fire? Thanks.

Simplified repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptLinkedItems" runat="server">            
    <ItemTemplate>      
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkLinked" runat="server" 
     Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkLinked_CheckedChanged" />
    </ItemTemplate>    
</asp:Repeater>
```

The collection is bound to the repeater as follows:

```
protected override void OnPreRenderComplete(EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        m_linkedItems = GetLinkedItems();
        rptLinkedItems.DataSource = GetLinkableItems();
        rptLinkedItems.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler
               (rptLinkedItems_ItemDataBound);
        rptLinkedItems.DataBind();
    }

    base.OnPreRenderComplete(e);
}
```

The OnItemDataBound event handler is as follows:

```
private void rptLinkedItems_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        CategoryItem item = args.Item.DataItem as CategoryItem;

        Literal litItemName = args.Item.FindControl("litItemName") as Literal;
        CheckBox chkLinked = args.Item.FindControl("chkLinked") as CheckBox;

        litItemName.Text = item.Text;

        chkLinked.Checked = IsItemLinked(item);
        chkLinked.AutoPostBack = true;
        chkLinked.InputAttributes.Add("Value", item.Id.ToString());
    }
}
```

The OnCheckedChanged event handler is as follows:

```
protected void chkLinked_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    CheckBox linkedItem = sender as CheckBox;
    Boolean itemState = linkedItem.Checked;
    Int32 itemId = Int32.Parse(linkedItem.InputAttributes["Value"].ToString());
    DataAccessLayer.UpdateLinkedItem(m_linkingItem, Utilities.GetCategoryItemFromId(itemId), itemState);
}
```

P.S. If someone can also tell me why markdown doesn't work correctly for me...

Comment: @Jibberish:  RE: your P.S.  You weren't doing it right. ;)  Try opening this question in edit mode and see what changes I made.  Key point 4 spaces to prefix code, which the editor instructs you to do in the right hand panel.

Comment: Thanks Anthony, and sorry I missed that in the editor.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is because the control hierarchy (and the check boxes in particular) don't exist when ASP.NET executes the `Control events` portion of the ASP.NET page life cycle, as you had created them in the later `PreRender` stages. Please see [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for more detailed overview of the event sequence.

**I would err on the side of caution for @bleeeah's advice, for you're assigning a value to `CheckBox.Checked` inside `rptLinkedItems_ItemDataBound`, which would also cause the event handler to execute:**

```
chkLinked.Checked = IsItemLinked(item);
```

Instead, move:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      m_linkedItems = GetLinkedItems();
      rptLinkedItems.DataSource = GetLinkableItems();
      rptLinkedItems.ItemDataBound += new RepeaterItemEventHandler
          (rptLinkedItems_ItemDataBound);
      rptLinkedItems.DataBind();
   }
```

Into the `Page.Load` event handler.

Comment: Thanks, Rabid. Have done that in addition to re-subscribing to the event as mentoined earlier and everything now works exactly as intended.

Comment: No problem, could you please vote up my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403? I'm desperate for some advice :)

Answer (score 44):

Try using`AutoPostBack="true"` like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkLinked" runat="server" Checked="false"
    OnCheckedChanged="chkLinked_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

Comment: I had one part of this correct, AutoPostBack completed my goals!

Comment: Perfect solution because AutoPostBack refresh the page after yuo change the state of the check box and so you can work on the property checkbox_checkchanged correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Try re-subscribing to the CheckChanged event in your OnItemDataBound event ,

```
chkLinked.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkLinked_CheckedChanged);
```

Comment: That appears to have solved the problem, thanks. I'm not clear on why though, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: It works because the event handlers of dynamic controls must be wired up every time the page is rebuilt.

Comment: Unless you do it in the Init, that way the framework takes care of this.

Comment: Thank you this one has solved my problem. I have added this into PageLoad function so i can link this oncheckchanged event to my fuction.

Answer (score 3):

Use `AutoPostBack="true"` like this:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkLinked" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
    Checked="false" OnCheckedChanged="chkLinked_CheckedChanged" />
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out :)

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the CheckChanged event in your Page_Init.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define eventhandler for checklist out of repeater item command, then inside the repeater item command, go through checklist items and get checked items.

In the .aspx page you can use Ajax and updatepanel to fire eventhandler, but keep in mind you have to define scriptmanage outside of repeater.

// checklisk checkedchange eventhandler

```
protected void chkLinked_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
        }
```

and item repeater command item:
// iterate checklist items and detect checked

```
    protected void Repeater1_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBoxList cbl = (CheckBoxList)e.Item.FindControl("CheckBoxList1");
        cbl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(chkLinked_CheckedChanged);

        string name = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < cbl.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (cbl.Items[i].Selected)
            {
                name += cbl.Items[i].Text.Split(',')[0] + ",";
            }
        }
    }
```