# Session Timeout and New Session

Tags: asp.net, session

If in an ASP.NET application the timeout happened and user is logged out. Will entering the Web App URL or opening a Page in the application makes a new session or renews the old session?(Browser shows same session ID, that makes me a bit more confused) whats the difference? Similarly, when a user closes the browser and reopens it after a timeout, will it be a new session or a renewal of old one?

This is quite a novice question but helps in my understanding of Sessions. pls clarify.

Comment: Do you mean, what happen when an user re-log in to application after a time out?

Comment: Are you using session.clear()? if so then it will show same session id.

Comment: I am using session. Abandon in a method to end session and not sure how asp.net ends the session... Thus need more insight into this

Answer (score 0):

You can have better understanding [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx). You can refer Sessions Identifier paragraph for it.

As well as [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net) link is also useful for complete understanding.

Answer (score 0):

`Session.Clear` or `Session.Abandon` is used to destroys a user session([Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470445/what-is-the-difference-between-session-abandon-and-session-clear)). `Session ID` is maintained within ASP.NET `session ID cookie`. So you have to remove cookie from the response itself.

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("YourSessionId");
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

For better understanding visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148647/generating-new-sessionid-in-asp-net)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: So if I add the above code to remove the sessionid cookie from response while ending user session , every time user logs out programmatically from my site and relogs it will be a new session right? Will the same happen with unbuilt session timeout in asp.net and whenever user closes and reopens the browser?

Comment: Give it a try definitely it will help you.