# How many bits have sessionid in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, sessionid

I want to ensure that the sessionid in asp.net have at least 128 bits.

Does anyone know how many bits the ASP.NET_SessionId have?

Can you find it somewhere in IIS?

Comment: why do you want to do so? [HTTPContext.Current.Session.SessionID](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403/generating-a-new-asp-net-session-in-the-current-httpcontext)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET uses an 120 bit identifier to track each session.

You can read the following articles.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918/en-us
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32545/Exploring-Session-in-ASP-Net
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7182/Session-management-options-in-ASP-NET

Comment: We have a demand to have at least 128 bits sessionid. Is there any way to change it to 128 bits?

Comment: I don't think you can change. Maybe in IIS.