# Managing Sessions across Tabs

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state, browser-cache, session-timeout

I have two apps(say App A and App B). App A gives a link to navigate to App B. On Initial load of App B, it creates a session with a new new Session Id. Further moving into the app, more values are stored in that session. If a select the link and do "open in new tab" multiple times, it will create a new GUID as a session id in each tab. Now i close all the tabs and come back to App A. App A doesn't have a session management mechanism and its session never expires but App B has and also has the session expire page.

After leaving the browser idle for sometime, say 20 mins or so when i try to navigate to the App B, it detects a expired session from the browsers cache and directly redirects to the session expire page of App B which is not an expected behavior. Every time a user tries to go to App B, He should have a fresh session.

Any suggestions on how to handle this scenario ?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403/generating-a-new-asp-net-session-in-the-current-httpcontext

Comment: How your app detects the session timeout condition ?