# DNN cookies not secure on all portals

Tags: security, cookies, dotnetnuke

I have a website in DNN 8.00.04.
Within this site I have 5 portals.

In the main portal all my cookies are secure and http only.
But on the other 4 portals they are not.

I have looked at the community of DNN but found nothing relevant.
How can i make sure that they are all secure ?

- The 'tankpas_cookie_accept' is a cookie I create in code and is set to secure and httpOnly.
- For the ASP.NET_SessionId I have used the following article to refresh the id:
  [Generating a new ASP.NET session in the current HTTPContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403/generating-a-new-asp-net-session-in-the-current-httpcontext)

But the other cookies are DNN cookies wich I don't know how to set them secure.

I allready tried to make the portal ssl enabled
through: Host - Site Management - (the portal) - Advanced setting - SSL Settings

SSL Enabled:   checked
SSL Enforced:  checked

--EDIT--
changing the webconfig from

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" domain="" />
```

to

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" domain="" />
```

Changing this however made the admin portal unavailable.

-- Edit 2--
Adding the following gives me a 505 Error when trying to open the site.

```
<rewrite>
   <outboundRules>
      <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
         <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
         <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
         </conditions>
         <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
      </rule>
   </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

[cookies main portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0i8o.png)

[cookies second portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWJjj.png)

Thx

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but you could enable [Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) in the Web.Config.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
        </rule>
      </outboundRules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

And enable [secure cookies](http://www.dotnetnoob.com/2010/11/how-to-secure-aspnet-cookies.html)

```
<system.web>
  <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="true" lockItem="true" />
</system.web>
```