# To Solve Session Fixation,suggested solution is to generate new SessionID after userLogin.I am unable to set new SessionId to CurrentContext.SessionID

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, sessionid

I found required solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403/generating-a-new-asp-net-session-in-the-current-httpcontext/4420114#4420114), But the solution uses reflection and sets the sessionId. In future if Asp.net internals get changed, this solution may break.

I tried,

```
SessionIDManager manager = new SessionIDManager();
string newSessionId = manager.CreateSessionID(context);
bool isAdd = false, isRedir = false;

// Save a new session ID
manager.SaveSessionID(context, newSessionId, out isRedir, out isAdd);
```

None of the method are setting `HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID`

Comment: The session id is auto generated, but it will not change until the cookie expired. Besides, the Session cookies are deleted when the browser session ends. I don't think you can change Session Id manually.