# ASP.NET application crashed when upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

I have an ASP.NET webforms application developed with .NET Framework 4.5.2.

When users log in, I generate a new `SessionID` and update it in the `Session` object following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368403/generating-a-new-asp-net-session-in-the-current-httpcontext/4420114#4420114). Everything works fine before I upgrade to .NET Framework 4.8.

With .NET Framework 4.8, when I login > logout > login again, then an unhandled exception is thrown and the application stops. The number of login > logout > login time is not fixed when it throws the exception. Sometimes it's 3, sometimes it's 5, sometimes it's 7,...

Below is the StackTrace:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll
> The thread 0x731c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> The thread 0x5f74 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> System.Transactions Critical: 0 : http://msdn.microsoft.com/TraceCodes/System/ActivityTracing/2004/07/Reliability/Exception/UnhandledUnhandled exception/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-133498638418308199System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
>
> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index
> at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at System.Web.Util.AspCompatApplicationStep.AnyStaObjectsInSessionState(HttpSessionState session)
> at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireSessionOnEnd(HttpSessionState session, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
> at System.Web.SessionState.SessionOnEndTargetWorkItem.RaiseOnEndCallback()
> at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
> at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
> Parameter name: index
> at System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
> at System.Web.Util.AspCompatApplicationStep.AnyStaObjectsInSessionState(HttpSessionState session)
> at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireSessionOnEnd(HttpSessionState session, Object eventSource, EventArgs eventArgs)
> at System.Web.SessionState.SessionOnEndTargetWorkItem.RaiseOnEndCallback()
> at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(WorkItemCallback callback)
> at System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(Object state)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
> at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

And here is the screenshot captured from the Visual Studio:

[image]

I'm trying to find out the root cause but still couldn't. Please give me advice.